# How to setText from intent data

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to set the text in a textview named `mUserTextView` with the data or result coming from another activity. I am using below code. But its not working. My app crashes with below code. Help Needed.

Activity 2: It has to transfer data to Activity 1.

```
private void enterClicked() {

        Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

        // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
        String editText = mEditText.getText().toString();

        // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
//      Intent result= new Intent()
        Intent result = new Intent(editText);


        // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);

        // TODO - Finish the Activity
        finish();

    }
```

Activity 1: Receiving data from Activity 2

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

            // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
            // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
            // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
            if (requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    mUserTextView.setText(data.getData().toString());// some problem in this line
                }
            }
        }
```

P.S: mUserTextView is adequately defined in the java file.

error: says `NullPointerException`

LogCat:

[image]

Comment: what error are you facing? post your logcat.

Comment: proper way to get data from intent is `data.getStringExtra("key");` . This will return a string . Store this string in a variable then put that variable in `setText()` method of textview . like this `setText(data.getStringExtra("key"))` . "key" is string which you have set during setting the data into the intent of the previous activity with `data.putExtra("key", stringData);`

Comment: I have made some edits in the question. Can you please look into it one more time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intent "data" object doesn't contain any data if you do not supply it while creating the Intent.

So,

```
data.getData().toString()
```

makes no sense.

If you are creating an Intent from Activity A, then in Activity B, do this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("KEY", "Put your value here");
 intent.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Then in your onActivityResult() do this,

```
if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("KEY"));
}
```

You can also send other data types like int, boolean, etc. Please check the methods, the usage is similar.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. It would be nice if you could just explain me this "KEY" thing. Is this "KEY" a inbuilt variable. How come we have not defined this "KEY" and yet it worked.

Comment: Is it some inbuilt global variable?

Comment: Yes surely I will. If this answer helped you please upvote it and ask a new question and give me the link. I will answer in detail. Thanks.

Comment: And please upVote my question. Since I have edited and provided all the details. :)

Comment: Okay done. You can give me the link to the new question here.

Comment: Just now surfed a little and got to know the MAP thing. So kind of got some idea of what we are doing here with the "KEY" . :) Thanks for the help. Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

I assumed that you are setting result like this :

```
   Intent in = new Intent();
   in.putExtra("text","This is demo text");
   in.setResult(RESULT_OK,in)
```

then in OnActivityResult() method ;

```
   mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("text"));
```

Comment: The parameters passed in setResult() method wrong. Please swap them.